# Calling UIKeyboard method on UITextView and not UITextFields

Tags: objective-c, nsnotifications

I have view with a `UITextView` for comments on the bottom.  Since its on the bottom of the page, whenever someone edits it, a method is called to shift the view of the page, so that you can still see the comment box.  My problem is that the same method also gets called when user are editing `UITextFields`.

Here's what I have.  First I declare a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                           object:self.view.window];
```

Then the method itself

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notif{

...

}
```

My first thought was to add a condition, to check and see if the object was a TextView, and only then execute the code.  But since I am not passing the object to the method, is there anyway to tell the method what type of object I am dealing with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text fields and text views also send notifications.  In the textFieldShouldBeginEditing and the textViewShouldBeginEditing implementations you could set a flag that you can read in your implementation of the keyboardWillShow method -- the keyboard notification is sent after the text field or text view notifications.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.sender = @"text field";
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    self.sender = @"text view";
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                               object:self.view.window];

}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notif{
    NSLog(@"%@",self.sender);
}
```

Comment: `self.sender` is looking for a variable class variable, instead of the parameter you're passing to the function.  Is this what you intended ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Sender (maybe that was a poor choice for the name), is just a property that I declared in the view controller's .h file. Does this not work for you?  I tested it, and it worked ok for me.

Comment: the textview one is not working for me... Why do you have the parameter as a textfield for the textview (I've tried it both ways but no luck).

Comment: never mind it is working now, using - `(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {`

and

`- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {`

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy and paste error. I've corrected it.  What is not working for you?  What does the log show in the keyboardWillShow method?

Comment: its working now, I had forgot to add UITextView to my `@interface` in the .h file.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you would do it that way. You could implement textFieldDidEndEditing (and the text view version) and do any readjusting of the views there.